# UserForm name printed in cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Extremely simple Useform and  4 text boxes:

- name
- surname
- Phone
- Address
  .

Some of my Code:

```
Private Sub Button_Add_Click()    
    Range("A2") = Name
    Range("B2") = Surname
    Range("C2") = Phone
    Range("D2") = Address    
End Sub
```

So after starting the Userform, it should show 4 text boxes, in which I put values and they are printed in the cells, right?

So I start userform, 4 boxes appear, so I enter:
(name)ABC
(surname)DEF
(Phone)123
(address)456

What I receive in the cells?

A2= UserForm1 B2=DEF C2=123 D2=456

Why the F... in cell A2, text UserForm1 is printed?! There is nothing more in the code!

Comment: `Name` is a builtin property of the UserForm object, so you can't call your textbox that. Try using another name like `tbName` or `userName` instead and it should work. Also as a tip, if your variables are ever automatically capitalised when you type them, it's a sign that you might be using a builtin, so I always name objects with a lowercase first letter (try typing `Range("A2") = Name` and you'll see what I mean)

Comment: Oh, it works. Thank you!